# Find pdf for $X*Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. We need to find the pdf for $X*Y$, BUT one is not allowed to use the differentiation under the integral sign rules, also note that $X$ and $Y$ take value $0$, so $\frac{X}{Y}$ does not necessarily make sense (I am not sure that an answer to the question exists).

Comment: * is multiplication?

Comment: What do you know about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$?  Are they independent?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $*$ is multiplication.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent, but we know that we deal with continuous random variables (if it helps somehow). If you can give an answer under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this using the change-of-variables formula of multivariate calculus. Assume that $(X,Y)$ have a joint probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Define $U=XY$, $V=Y$. The transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ is one-to-one if we restrict to $y\neq 0$, and since $Y$ is a continuous random variable, we have $P(Y=0)=0$, so there is no problem in making this restriction. The inverse transformation is given by $X=U/V, Y=V$. We compute the determinant of the Jacobian matrix
$$\det J = \det \pmatrix{ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}}
=\det \pmatrix{ 1/v & -u/v^2 \\ 0 & 1} = 1/v$$
The probability density of $(U,V)$ is then
$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(u/v,v)|J| = f_{X,Y}(u/v,v)/|v|$$
To obtain the marginal density of $U=XY$, we then integrate
$$f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(u/v,v)/|v|\ dv$$
Finally, to get the CDF of $U$, we integrate again:
$$F_U(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(u/v,v)/|v|\ dv\ du$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would need a bit more rigor at the point where you say "...and since $Y$ is a continuous random variable, we have $P(Y=0)=0$, so there is no problem in making this restriction..." In the formulation of the density transformation theorem I have, there is a clear requirement that $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ must be invertible, and in our case the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)$ strictly speaking is not invertible, so I decided not to use this theorem for this problem.

Comment: We could make it rigorous like this: Define a new random variable $Y_0$ which modifies $Y$ to make it never be zero,
$$Y_0=\begin{cases}Y, &\text{if $Y\neq 0$} \\ 1,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $Y_0=Y$ with probability 1, so $(X,Y_0)$ has the same distribution as $(X,Y)$, so without loss of generality we can just assume that $Y$ is never 0. Then the domain of the transformation can be taken to exclude $y=0$, so the transformation will then be one-to-one on the whole domain.

Comment: Then I am afraid we have another problem: in my formulation of the theorem it is stated that the following condition need to be satisfied $P((X,Y) \in M)=1$ where $M$ is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$. If we take out $0$ as you suggest, then $M$ is not connected any longer. I do not know how crucial this requirement is for the theorem.

Comment: In that case, how about expressing the integral as the sum of two integrals, one for each of the two connected components?

Answer (score 0):

The cdf $F_Z(z)$ for $Z = XY$ is the probability (for the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$) of the region $A(z) = \{(x,y) \in R^2: xy \le z\}$.  If $z < 0$ this can be written as $\{(x,y): y \ge z/x, x < 0\} \cup \{(x,y): y \le z/x, x > 0\}$.
If $z > 0$ it is the complement of 
$\{(x,y): y < z/x, x < 0\} \cup \{(x,y): y > z/x, x > 0\}$.  You can't say more without knowing something about the joint distribution.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ and cdf's $F_X$ and $F_Y$ respectively,
then e.g. for $z < 0$ we have
$$ \eqalign{F_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^0 dx \int_{0}^{z/x} dy\; f_X(x) f_Y(y) + \int_0^\infty dx \int_{z/x}^0 dy \; f_X(x) f_Y(y)\cr
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 dx\; f_X(x) (F_Y(z/x) - F_Y(0)) + 
\int_0^\infty dx\; f_X(x) (F_Y(0) - F_Y(z/x))\cr
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 dx\; f_X(x) F_Y(z/x) - \int_0^\infty dx\; f_X(x)  F_Y(z/x) + (1 - 2 F_X(0)) F_Y(0)}$$
I'll leave the case $z > 0$ to you.

Comment: I am very very sorry, but what I meant was not cdf, but rather pdf (I initially formulated the question in a wrong way). To take your answer to the pdf one would be inclined to apply the differentiation under the integral rule, but I am wondering whether one can get away without it.

Comment: Robert, are you sure that for the case $z<0$ you found above $F_Z$ and not $1-F_Z$?